# JSonDecoder() Swift 4 Decoding error

Tags: json, xcode

I am getting an error when trying to decode Json in swift 4

typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Swift._DictionaryCodingKey(stringValue: "ThrottleSeconds", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Json reply is

{"Response":"4611686018456390681","ErrorCode":1,"ThrottleSeconds":0,"ErrorStatus":"Success","Message":"Ok","MessageData":{}}

```
struct BasicReply: Decodable {

let Response : String?
let ErrorCode : Int?
let ThrottleSeconds : Int?
let ErrorStatus : String?
let Message : String?
let MessageData : String?
}

class NetworkRequests {
let api = apiDetails()


func buildRequests()->String{

    let request = "1/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/" + api.userName + "/"

   // let request = "1/Account/" + api.membershipId + "/Summary/"
    return request
}
func request(){


    let destinyURL : String = api.destinyURL + buildRequests()
    let url = NSURL(string: destinyURL)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    // add headers
    request.setValue(api.apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-Key")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let destinySession = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let code = response.statusCode
            print(code)
        }

        guard let data = data else {print("No DATA!!!");return}
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("output ", output! as Any)

        do {

            let questions = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: BasicReply].self, from: data)

        } catch let jsonErr {

            print("Error decoding Json Questons", jsonErr)
        }
    }
    destinySession.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: The error message does not match the struct and the JSON, `messageData` (please name variables with a starting lowercase letter) is declared as `String` (not a number) but in the JSON it's a `Dictionary`. A dictionary cannot be decoded without further code anyway, you will get a `does not conform` error. And if the JSON is the real response the passed type `[String: BasicReply]` is wrong, too. Finally, optional constants `let ... String?` are nonsensical.

Comment: My understating of variable names in this case that have to match the Json Names And the optional allows the variable to be nil and as far as i can see the MessageData is and empty object not a number?

Comment: The error message clearly states *...but found a **number** instead*. Use custom coding keys to map the uppercase keys to lowercase variables.

Comment: I must be missing the point here ThrottleSeconds is the error and i have declared as Int what more can i do ?

Comment: Not as straight forward as explained on several forums and videos then maybe this link might help others https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375